# Why emulator closes after a fake call

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I don't know what is happening with my android  emulator ! when i make a fake call from DDMS the emulator close all process in the Device section !
I'm using Android 4.4 API 19 with Eclipse Helios 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in the new SDK. I am having the same problem but I'm using 4.3. When a call is placed ADB loses connection to the emulator for some reason. I get the same problem whether I use the DDMS or whether I place the call by connecting to the emulator via telnet.

You need to run `adb kill-server` followed by `adb devices`. You can just run `adb start-server` but I tend to use devices instead as this will restart ADB and once started show the device listing so you can double check the emulator has reconnected.

I have tried using http://genymotion.com for the emulator. It works a lot better, and a lot more faster than the official SDK emulator however it doesn't seem to be able to place calls. At least not that I can find.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i'll try your method to handle this . can you advice with is the best version of Android stable ! ,I don't know Genymotion it's another android Emulator ? i can't find the download link in the site !

Comment: For Genymotion you need to sign up, there are free/paid versions depending on your usage. I did however, contact the developer regarding the phone use, and they came back and said as yet genymotion doesn't yet support phone calls however, they're hoping to release this within the next few months.

Comment: Regarding the best android version to use, it is always best to target the latest version of the Android API. All versions of Android are considered stable, although the latest KitKat release could have bugs, but these are likely to fairly minor bugs which shouldn't really impact on development

Comment: Thanks for your help ! i'll give a try ! and i hope it will work !

Comment: I have tried android 4.3 !! all is working fine ! thanks for the help

Comment: If you are finding that this answer fixed your issue, then please accept :)